# Calling a proxy created via component binding on a thread other than a Mule thread

Tags: mule

Can an application make a call on a proxy created via component binding on a non-Mule thread i.e. a thread created by the application? I am trying to do that and I get a NullPointerException on org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent:268.

That's on Mule EE 3.3.0

Thanks.

UPDATE:

**The Mule code**

```
<mule ...>
    <vm:endpoint path="entryPoint" name="entryPoint" />

    <flow name="entryPoint.Flow">
        <inbound-endpoint ref="entryPoint" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <component class="foo.Component">
            <binding interface="foo.Interface" method="echo">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="foo.Interface.echo" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        </binding>
        </component>
    </flow>

    <flow name="foo.Interface.echo">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="foo.Interface.echo" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <logger level="INFO" />
    </flow>

</mule>
```

**The Java component**

```
package foo;

import static java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Component {

    private Interface i;

    public String foo(final String input) {
        return callInterfaceOnAWorkerThreadWith(input);
    }

    public void setInterface(final Interface i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    private String callInterfaceOnAWorkerThreadWith(final String input) {
        ExecutorService executorService = newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<String> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {

            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return i.echo(input);
            }

        });
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

**The Java interface**

```
package foo;

public interface Interface {

    String echo(String input);

}
```

**The test fixture to execute the mule app**

```
package foo;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.client.MuleClient;
import org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest extends FunctionalTestCase {

    @Test
    public void echo() {
        final MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
        MuleMessage reply = send(client, "entryPoint", "a string");
        assertEquals("a string", reply.getPayload());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "app/componentbindingonanotherthread.xml";
    }

    private MuleMessage send(final MuleClient client, final String url, final Object payload) {
        try {
            return client.send(url, payload, null, RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);
        } catch (final MuleException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Executing the code above shows the following exception in the logs:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.<init>(DefaultMuleEvent.java:268)
    at org.mule.component.BindingInvocationHandler.invoke(BindingInvocationHandler.java:96)
    at $Proxy14.echo(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "created by the application"? What application? The Mule application? Maybe showing config and code snippets would help better understand the issue.

Comment: @DavidDossot - Java code and Mule code added as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boils down to the fact that Mule's `BindingInvocationHandler` looks-up the current `MuleEvent` by using `RequestContext.getEvent()`, which is `ThreadLocal`-bound. In other words, since you're performing the binding in another thread, the Mule context is lost and you get the above failure.

Using Mule's worker manager (that you can get from the MuleContext), which would be a better design that use your own `ExecutorService`, would still not solve the problem because of the reliance of `BindingInvocationHandler` on the (deprecated!) `RequestContext.getEvent()` construct.

I think you need to rethink your design because, when you really look into it, it doesn't make much sense IMO. Executing the binding on another thread doesn't buy you anything since the `entryPoint` is request-response so an inbound thread is mobilized out of the pool. This thread remains blocked until the binding is finished, whether the binding itself is performed by this thread or another thread.

If, for a reason that escapes me, you really need to perform the binding in another thread, then move the binding in another flow and invoke it with a [`request-reply` message processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-RequestReply).

The lesson here is: Mule has a rich threading model already and it's better to play within it by using the threading constructs it offers (`request-reply`, `async`, `one-way` VM queues) rather than coding your own.

Comment: My use case is a fully parallelizable computation ... I ended up using Mule's scatter-gather idiom (which makes use of a `request-reply` block and a couple of `one-way` flows). The reason I first tried to use the Java's concurrency facilities is because I find them more readable (and I was somewhat more familiar with them)